# Android app that opens then closes youtube video

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

Sorry, my code is a bit spaghetti at the moment but I just had a general question.  I have an android app where a user taps a button which is supposed to open youtube, play a 10 second clip, then close youtube and the user continues on in the activity.  I've been able to get the video to come up by doing

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
```

and launching that intent, however my question is how do you close the video when it's done?
I can get the activity back by calling `startActivity()` after a `postDelayed()` equal to the length of the video, however the youtube window simply goes into picture-in-picture rather than closing.  Calling the `finish()` method just closes my main activity.

Is there a solution for this, or is the picture-in-picture function of an external program (namely the youtube app) not alterable from within my app?

Comment: In this case, why don't you implement youtube player view in your app instead of opening the youtube app via Intent. IMO

Comment: will give that a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off creating a new activity, embedding the video player into that activity and then using startAcitivty to go back.

I think the problem is when the Youtube App opens, that app now has control and it's not really good for your app to be able to open itself (which is what it is doing really) after a certain time limit.
You can use the Youtube API to embed it so it is not so hard and will be easier than what you described.